# Is there a version of linux that can be run on the 2015 Kindle Fire

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, hardware-compatibility

I have been doing some research and I have been reading all kinds of answers but none of them fully answer my question. I wanted to know if the [2015 Kindle Fire](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TSUGXKE) can support a version of Linux? If so, where can I find this Linux distribution.

I have seen somethings about different operating systems for the generation one but I have not been able to find anything about the latest cheapest generation.

A tutorial I saw [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIYKKLX8lJM) to put Ubuntu on a Kindle, an Android tablet. Kindle Fire is Android-based.

Comment: Don't have the time to put everything into an answer, but I can point you in the right direction. Look for the `linuxforandroid ubuntu installer` should start you on the right path at least :)

Answer (score 1):

Do note that your device is in fact named as the `Amazon Fire` (7 inch, 2015, 5th generation, codename `ford`). This accurate naming makes all the difference between other Amazon's devices.

Now, if you want to replace your Android with a normal Linux, that will virtually not happen any soon since it took 4 years to unlock your Fire's bootloader and have a custom recovery. In 2021, it still only have few custom ROMs, which means we're still very far from having a true Linux running on it.

However, if you still want to run a real x64 Linux inside your Android, there's the virtualization way with [`Bochs`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.bochs&hl=en_US&gl=US).

If you know how to use VirtualBox, KVM/QEMU, VMWare on PC, things will be pretty simple.

Do note that virtualization/emulation may fail or crash if your device's stock ROM is too heavily modified. If that happens, you may first switch to a custom ROM that respects Android official specifications better, like [LineageOS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-unlocked-ford-austin-lineage-14-1-17-jan-2021.3962457/). This will also bring Android 7.1 (Nougat) to your Fire.